# import pyautogui does not work in VSCode, despite having everything installed

Tags: python, python-import, pyautogui

Im learning Python at the moment and I am trying to work with pyautogui at the moment but I have encountered a very basic problem and while I found other questions like this, I did not find a solution.

My "Setup":
I am on Windows 10 64 bit, I have installed python 3.11, I have the 22.3.1 pip version and the 0.9.53 version of pyautogui installed
I am using Visual Studio Code.

Now I want to just simply move my mouse a bit, nothing special. But I am getting stuck at the very beginning, when I try to import pyautogui.
it looks like this:
[image: A screenshot of VSCode]
The Problem Tab just mentions "pyautogui: Unknown word".

The thing is, if I test it in the terminal, it works without a problem it just seems like VSCode cant import pyautogui.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python, the package and creating new files. Nothing seems to really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the visual studio code problem, It is because you have the `Code Spell Checker` extension installed in your `VScode`. This extension checks the spelling of the `pyautogui` word and because the extension is not found in their dictionary it highlights the word.

##### This extension only checks the spelling. So your code can run without error.

Ways to solve this error.

1. Hover over the word `pyautogui` and click Quick Fix and then add this word to your `user` or `workspace` dictionary. (Shortcut for Quick fix. `Ctrl + .`)
   [image][image]
2. Go to the extension tab and search this `streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker`. Then disable or uninstall the extension [image]

Comment: Okay, not gonna lie, it seems my brain just didnt work. What I actually wanted was "moveTo", and not whatever I was doing there. So ofcourse the code does nothing, since I didnt give it any real task. The Spellchecking must have confused me way more than I thought. I guess I can delete this question now.

Comment: @ProjectDean If spellchecking confuses you then uninstall or disable it from the extension tab. search `streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker` in the extension tab.